# OpenCV FileStorage writes hyphens and periods

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a problem with the writing of yaml file. I collect some data (e.g. 50) from three sources and write the data into a cv::Mat.

I initialize the cv::FileStorage and then wait until the data is collected.

```
void mainGui::initialize()
{
  cv::FileStorage m_Fs;
  m_Fs.open(m_FsFileName, CV_STORAGE_WRITE);
}
```

If enough data is there then I append the already created file:

```
void mainGui::save()
{
  m_Fs.open(m_FsFileName, CV_STORAGE_APPEND);

  if(m_Fs.isOpened())
  {
    m_Fs << sensorId.toStdString() << dataMat;
    m_Fs.release();
  }
}
```

The content of written output file looks like:

```
%YAML:1.0

sensor1: !!opencv-matrix
rows: 50
cols: 3
dt: d
data: [ 7.1709999084472656e+01, -2.5729999542236328e+01,
   -1.4074000549316406e+02 ...]
...
---
sensor2: !!opencv-matrix
rows: 50
cols: 3
dt: d
data: [ 8.1040000915527344e+01, -1.2619999885559082e+01,
   -1.2151999664306641e+02, ...]
...
---
sensor3: !!opencv-matrix
rows: 50
cols: 3
dt: d
data: [ 8.1040000915527344e+01, -1.2619999885559082e+01,
   -1.2151999664306641e+02, ...]
```

As you see, It separates three data with hyphens (---) and periods (...). If I want to read the file I get syntax error. How can I avoid so that this hyphens and periods not to be written?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to read the input file with *"what"*?

Comment: With FileStorage again (CV_STORAGE_READ). If I remove the ... and --- manually than there is no problem by reading

Comment: Does it work if you remove them with `grep -vE '^---|^\.\.\.' originalFile > editedFile`

Comment: Yes, then it works..

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the answer but maybe that little work-around will keep you going till someone comes up with a proper answer. Good luck!